# Flutter trigger action in child with InheritedWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, inherited-widget

I have a dice-rolling `MaterialApp`. When the `floatingButton` is pressed I want to trigger a "dice-roll" on the children. I'm trying to use the InheritedWidget, but most examples I've seen appear to do the opposite, trigger a parent change from the child.

The Stateless Parent:

```dart
class DiceApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                RollTrigger(
                  roller: Roller(),
                  child: Die(),
                ),
                RollTrigger(
                  roller: Roller(),
                  child: Die(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.casino),
          onPressed: () {
            // Trigger the dice roll on each
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
}
```

The `InheritedWidget`:

```dart
class RollTrigger extends InheritedWidget {
  RollTrigger({this.roller, this.child});

  final roller;
  final Widget child;

  static RollTrigger of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<RollTrigger>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(RollTrigger oldWidget) => true;
}
```

I'm *trying* using a `Roller` class to trigger the roll action:

```dart
class Roller {
  bool rolling = false;

  void roll(_DieState die) {
    die.roll();
  }
}
```

And finally the Stateful Die:

```dart
class Die extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DieState createState() => _DieState();
}

class _DieState extends State<Die> {

  int value = 0;
  final _random = new Random();
  roll() {
    this.value = 1 + _random.nextInt(6 - 1);
  }

  _DieState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var roller = RollTrigger.of(context).roller;

    return Text(this.value.toString());
  }
}
```

This seems like it should be simpler, but I'm tying myself in knots here.

Edit: I'm updating by putting the Roller at the top level per suggestion. I'm still not sure how to trigger a rebuild for the bottom widget:

```dart
final Roller roller = Roller();
...
  RollTrigger(
    roller: this.roller,
    child: Die(),
)
```

And then I put the roll method in the Roller:

```dart
class Roller {

  int value = 0;

  final _random = new Random();

  void roll() {

    this.value = 1 + _random.nextInt(6 - 1);

    print(this.value);

  }
}
```

Assign the value from the `Roller`:

```dart
class _DieState extends State<Die> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final roller = RollTrigger.of(context).roller;

    return Text(roller.value.toString());
  }
}
```

And finally, call the `roll` method at the top level:

```dart
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.casino),
          onPressed: () {
            this.roller.roll();
          },
        ),
```

This updates the `Roller`'s value, but never changes to value of the _DieState... which is the problem I'm trying to solve. There are a lot of interesting patterns out there, but I *think* what I'm struggling with is the basic implementation.

Comment: This approach is a bit wonky, but it would work. The reason it isn't currently working is that you are never calling actually calling `Roller.roll`.

Comment: yeah, wonky is a good description. I guess I'm not even sure where to run `Roller.roll()`. I have access to the Roller in the Die, but how do I trigger that from the top level? (that's the whole thing I'm trying to solve)

Comment: You need to maintain an instance of `Roller` in the top level. Right now you are creating the instance at the moment of the build, but you can create the instance as a class field so you can reference it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems like it should be simpler, but I'm tying myself in knots here.

Yes. It should be much simpler!

You need to take advantage of the observer design pattern. In Flutter, an observable is a `ChangeNotifier`.

Package provider will help a great deal. All the widget classes you create can be `StatelessWidget`.

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Die with ChangeNotifier {
  //
  // _value can be one of null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
  // A value of null signifies the die is currently rolling.
  //
  int _value = 1;

  final Random _random = Random();

  int get value {
    return this._value;
  }

  Future<void> roll() async {
    if (this._value == null) {
      // already rolling
      return;
    }

    this._value = null;
    this.notifyListeners();

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    this._value = 1 + this._random.nextInt(6);
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Die Rolling App',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Die>(
          create: (final BuildContext context) {
            return Die();
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Die Rolling Game")),
        body: Center(child: DieDisplay()),
        floatingActionButton: RollFAB(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DieDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Die>(
      builder: (final BuildContext context, final Die die, final Widget child) {
        return Text((die.value == null) ? 'rolling' : die.value.toString());
      },
    );
  }
}

class RollFAB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        final Die die = Provider.of<Die>(context, listen: false);
        die.roll();
      },
      tooltip: 'Roll',
      child: const Icon(Icons.casino),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great. If I'm reading correctly, instead of the `InheritedWidget` you're using the `Provider.of` with `MultiProvider` and the `notifiyListeners` and the display uses the `Consumer`. :thumbs-up: thanks

Comment: Yes package provider makes for some very clean code. If you'll only have one provider then `MultiProvider` isn't necessary. I included it because often there are multiple providers.